# Pad Spacing violates trace spacing

Tags: trace, pad, spacing

How does one deal with a situation where a trace has particular clearance spec to other nets, but that clearance spec is not respected by the pads on a component that the net attaches to?

A simple example is attaching a chassis ground line, which can see high voltages during an ESD event, to a high-value bleed-off resistor or a bypass cap attached to ground.  The pads underneath the component are much closer together than the minimum spacing, unless I use a very large footprint part.  Is there a better way?  Or am I overthinking this?

Answer (score 3):

You need a large footprint part. If you need 5 mm clearance, you can't just use an 0805 capacitor or resistor and expect to have your clearances satisfied; you would want to use a properly rated high-voltage part, which should have appropriate clearance and creepage due to its design. That may mean wide lead spacing on a through-hole diode, or the use of an extra-wide SOIC package for an isolation IC, or even a bespoke package designed specifically to accommodate clearance and creepage requirements, but you definitely shouldn't just use an ordinary part.